# Non model-theoretic, constructive proof that it is valid to introduce new unique constants in a first order theory with equality

Tags: logic, reference-request, alternative-proof, proof-theory

I'm currently reading through Mendelson's `Introduction to Mathematical Logic', and one of the proofs has left me dissatisfied.

In general, I am fine with seeing metamathematical results proven using model theory, so long as they are not too fundamental - i.e. if I feel that one could develop a theory without these results that is sufficiently strong to in principle be later used as a metatheory to prove said results in. This is why I am fine with the completeness theorem being proved using model theoretic tools, as I believe that one can develop set theory without it to the point that one could then use that set theory as a metatheory in which model theoretic results can be proved.

I run into a problem with this view in chapter 2.9. of Mendelson's book, however, as a result is proved using model theory that I view as being absolutely funadamental. Proposition 2.28 of this chapter essentially states that if $K$ is a first order theory with equality, and $\vdash_K (\exists ! u)\beta(u, x_1, \dots , x_n)$, then the theory $K^*$ obtained by adding to $K$ a new function letter $f$ of $n$ arguments along with the proper axiom $\beta(f(x_1, \dots, x_n), x_1, \dots , x_n)$ and instances of other logical axioms that need be amended is in a sense `equivalent' to $K$. There is an effective procedure which shows that any theorem provable in $K^*$ is also provable in $K$ (and vice versa, of course).

I view it as fundamental that one may introduce new constants whenever one has shown unique existence, without adding strength to a theory, but the proof this book uses for this is model theoretic and non-constructive.

The author acknowledges this later on, stating that Kleene gives a constructive syntactical proof in his 1952 text `Introduction to metamathematics' but I cannot easily get a hold of this book in order to see the proof.

I am wondering here if anyone would be able to give the proof, or at least an outline, or direct me to where I can find a proper, syntactical proof of the theorem in Mendelson's book. I would like to at least be able to view the page of Kleene's book in which the result is proved, and if it looks good enough I'll buy the text (since I imagine the proof will rely on earlier lemmas I'd need to dig into), but so far I haven't be able to find a preview of the page.

Comment: See George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1: Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA112) (2003): **Ch.I.7. Defined Symbols**, page 112-on: **Th.I.7.1 Metatheorem (Elimination of Defined Symbols: I)** and **Th.I.7.3 Metatheorem (Elimination of Defined Symbols: II)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise in what follows, here are what I am assuming are the axioms:

1. $(\beta\rightarrow (\alpha\rightarrow \beta))$
2. $((\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow ((\alpha\rightarrow (\beta\rightarrow \gamma))\rightarrow (\alpha\rightarrow \gamma)))$
3. $(((\alpha\rightarrow \bot)\rightarrow \bot)\rightarrow \alpha)$
4. $(\forall x (\varphi\rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\varphi\rightarrow \forall x \psi))$ whenever $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are wffs, $x$ is a variable, and $x$ is not free in $\varphi$
5. $\forall x \varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi(y)$ whenever $\varphi(x)$ is a wff with free variable $x$, $y$ is a variable or constant, and no free occurence of $x$ in $\varphi(x)$ is within the scope of a $\forall y$
6. $(t=t)$ whenever $t$ is a term
7. $((x=y)\rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \psi))$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are variables or constants, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are wffs, and $\psi$ is obtained by substituting $y$ for some free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$.

Along with the rules of inference given by Modus Ponens and Generalization.

The main tool to use after this is the Deduction Theorem, which I assume if fundamental enough that you're familiar with it.

Something additional I will assume you'll be fine with is the fact that if $\Phi$ is a consistent set of sentences in a signature $\sigma$, then expanding $\sigma$ with new constants (giving, say, $\sigma'$) still leaves $\Phi$ consistent.  Basically, the proof is that we can transform any proof of $\bot$ from $\Phi$ over $\sigma'$ into a proof of $\bot$ from $\Phi$ over $\sigma$ by replacing any newly-used constants with unused variables.

This same idea is used to show that if $\Phi \vdash \exists x \varphi(x)$ then $\Phi \cup \{\varphi(c)\}$ is consistent (over the new language), where $c$ is some new constant.  Indeed, suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $\Phi \cup \{\varphi(c)\} \vdash \bot$, so that by the Deduction Theorem we have $\Phi \vdash (\varphi(c) \to \bot)$.  Take the proof of $\varphi(c) \to \bot$ and turn it into a proof of $\varphi(x) \to \bot$, using the fact that relative to $\Phi$ there isn't anything special about the constant $c$ and so replacing it with any other constant or variable shouldn't affect the validity of the proof.  By generalization, we find that $\Phi \vdash \forall x (\varphi(x) \to \bot)$.

Now, $\Phi \vdash \exists x \varphi(x)$ by hypothesis.  $\exists x \varphi(x)$ is the same as $\neg \forall x \neg \varphi(x)$, or $((\forall x (\varphi(x) \to \bot))\to \bot)$.  But we've shown that $\Phi \vdash \forall x (\varphi(x) \to \bot)$, and so by Modus Ponens we have $\Phi \vdash \bot$, contradicting the assumed consistency of $\Phi$.

At this point we can prove your result (though what we've done above is remarkably close). Suppose $\Phi \vdash \exists u \varphi(u,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ for every $x_1,\ldots, x_n$.  Then we can choose for $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ a constant symbol $c_{x_1,\ldots, x_n}$ and add $\varphi(c_{x_1,\ldots, x_n},x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ to $\Phi$. From the above, the resulting theory is consistent.

Now add a function symbol $f$ and add the sentences $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=c_{x_1,\ldots, x_n}$ to $\Phi$. Now all we need to do is show that the resulting theory is consistent. But this follows almost immediately from the same kinds of arguments from above: if we have a proof of $\bot$, we can just replace any instance of $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ with $c_{x_1,\ldots, x_n}$ to get the necessary contradiction.

Comment: This seems to work, so thank you, might need to puzzle over some small bits but I think that's just an issue on my end

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you've only proved that the new system is consistent, not that there is a transformation F between K and $K^*$ such that if one can prove $F(\Phi)$ in $K^*$ then one can prove $\Phi$ in K. Mendelson's theorem implies, I believe, that the new theory $K^*$ is no stronger than K.

Comment: If you have access to Mendelson's book it might be a good idea to see which theorem I am referring to, as I gave mostly a synopsis in my question

Comment: @Nethesis Ah, I missed that aspect of your question.  I don't have access to Mendelson's book, but I would imagine you can finagle up some such $F$ in the same way that we can transform any proof using $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ with $c_{x_1,\ldots, x_n}$, and then do similarly with any use of $c_{x_1,\ldots, x_n}$ and a formula involving $\exists u \varphi(u,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, but I don't have the time to flesh that out.

Comment: It is okay, in retrospect I should have added more detail. I managed to find Kleene's proof so the problem's been sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to track down Kleene's book, the proof is very complex comparatively, but seems sufficient. I've decided to post a few pictures of his proof for anyone who later looks, hopefully this is allowed, if not I'll take them down:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTm9N.jpg

If any future readers see this, know that you may need to actually get ahold of the book in order to fully follow the proof, though what is given there is pretty well written in my opinion. At the very least it may convince you to get the book, or be satisfied that a syntactic proof exists.